# Some module is adding info below 'Nice Menus'

Tags: 6

I believe some module is somehow hooking into nice menus and adding a div of content below the menu. However I can't for the life of me find out which one.

Here's what I know:

There is a content type called 'nice_menu_addition'. When creating an item of that content type you chose which menu item you would like it placed beneath, and it shows up there. However, I can't find ANY modules anywhere, or any theme info that shows where this is being done. Any suggestions as to where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suggestion from average drupal guy.... try using the [module_implements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_implements/6) with watchdog method to check the available hooks from nice menu or menu docs that can cause the change and track the module...hope it helps you in some way

Comment: Agreed, that's a great option. Also, would it be worth doing a global search of codebase for 'nice_menu_addition'?

Comment: Thanks you guys, that was a good suggestion, but it actually ended up being a view that was attaching itself to the menu. That's why I couldn't find anything in any of the modules. I'm checking this though since it was the best suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Would [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) give you the module function that was generating the spurious info?